# How to write regular expression for 16 digit ID, rules mentioned below?

Tags: regex, informatica, regular-language

I have to write regular expression in informatica data quality for 16 digit ID which should follow below set of validation.
ID Must have 16 characters and follow below rules-

1. First 6 must be alphabetic characters
2. Position 7 & 8 are numeric digits
3. Position 9 alphabetic character
4. Position 10 &11 are numeric digits
5. Position 12 alphabetic character
6. Position 13-15 are numeric digits
7. Position 16 alphabetic character

I have tried with many ways , not working as expected.Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z][0-9]{2}[A-Za-z][0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]$
```

Note that if the alphabetic characters would be only exlcusively uppercase or lowercase, then you may replace the chracter class `[A-Za-z]` with either just `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`.

Comment: Unless you are matching a single "statement", \b might be better as bounds (rather than ^ and $)

Comment: I understand the Informatica regex engine uses [Perl-compatible syntax](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-2/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_match.html). If so, subroutines could be used here:  `^([A-Za-z]){6}([0-9]){2}(?1)(?2){2}(?1)(?2){3}(?1)$`.